# Cannot run Tensorflow code multiple times in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: tensorflow, ipython, jupyter-notebook, autoencoder

I'm struggling running Tensorflow (v1.1) code multiple times in Jupyter Notebook.

For example, I execute  this simple code snippet that creates an encoding layer for a seq2seq model:

```
# Construct encoder layer (LSTM)
encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(encoder_hidden_units)
encoder_outputs, encoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    encoder_cell, encoder_inputs_embedded, 
    dtype=tf.float32, time_major=False
)
```

**First time is totally fine, my encoder is created.**

However, if I rerun it (no matter the changes I've applied), I get this error:
`Attempt to have a second RNNCell use the weights of a variable scope that already has weights`

It's very annoying as it forces me to restart the kernel every time I want to change a layer.

Can someone explain me why this happens and how I can fix this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if some of you have great tutorials on how to implement basic seq2seq models in Tensorflow 1.1, don't hesitate to share it! Unfortunately, the [seq2seq tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq) is outdated and deprecated in favor of the [new seq2seq API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq)

Comment: Following @Nicolas answer, the same would have happened in the Python shell. Tensorflow raises an error when we try to reconstruct an existing node from the graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to build the exact same graph twice and therefore TensorFlow complains because the variables already exist in the default graph.

What you could do is to call `tf.reset_default_graph()` before trying to call the method a second time to ensure you create a new graph when required.

Just in case, I would also suggest using an interactive session as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) in the *Start TensorFlow InteractiveSession* section:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

Comment: Only slightly more explicit than @pfm, I found that the following works: import tensorflow as tf; tf.reset_default_graph();